# ExtJS DateField using datetime format

Tags: datetime, extjs, format, datefield

```
var todate = new Ext.form.DateField({
        format: 'd/m/Y', 
        fieldLabel: '',
        id: 'txtExpireDate',
        name: 'txtExpireDate',
        width: 150,
        allowBlank: false,
        value: '',
        renderTo: 'divDateExpire'
    });
```

This code to display only date. How to use datetime format?

Thank you

Comment: Which datetime format are you talking about? You have to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In `Ext.Form.DateField` we're not able to show time directly when selecting a date in date picker. For that we add listeners:

```
var dtpIssueDate = new Ext.form.DateField({
  listeners: {
    select: function(dtpIssueDate, date) {
      BindTimeWithDate(date);
    }
  }
});

//Bind time with date selected in the picker
function BindTimeWithDate(date) {
  try {
    var currentTime = new Date()

    // Get a current hours and add with date.
    date.setHours(currentTime.getHours());

    // Get a current minutes and add with date.
    date.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes());

    dtDateTimeValue = date.format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    dtpIssueDate.SetText(dtDateTimeValue); 
  }
  catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no component in extjs library which can display date & time both. And thus, you cannot use date time format in one. The closest one can get to is [with  this.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?22661-new-version-DateTime-Field)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have solution for this question. By set format: 'd/m/Y  H:i:s'